# How to get the text in the image view field in Ui automator

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NnCU.png)

Hi, I am trying to validate the results of the messages being sent and received, is there a way I can fetch the text in the image view field and validate on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following line of code to validate message on image.

```
        driver.findElement(By.name("id of text in image"));
        String text = driver.findElement(By.name("id of text in image")).getText();
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("Message that is to be checked")) {
            System.out.println("Existing Message is correct.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Existing Message is wrong.");

        }
```